# How can I select tags from MySQL sorted by creation_date and name but remove duplicate name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I'm using MySQL and Laravel 3.

I have the following table:

```
tags
  id         INT
  name       INT
  created_at TIMESTAMP
```

tag names are not unique and tags are associated with another table called `cases` via a pivot table.

I need to grab the most recently created 50 tags sorted by name). The catch is that I only want one instance of a named tag (e.g. if there are two tags called 'funny' then I only want to return the most recent one.

For instance, suppose this is my tags table:

```
id   name     created_at
1    funny    2013-4-10
2    sad      2013-6-5
3    angry    2013-1-3
4    funny    2013-6-7
5    grumpy   2013-5-20
```

I want to return the tags in the following order:

```
funny(4)
sad(2)
grumpy (5)
angry(3)
```

Note how only one 'funny' tag is being returned (the most recent one).

I've tried this:

```
$tags = DB::table('tags')->order_by('created_at', 'desc')->group_by('name')->distinct()->take(50)->get();?>
```

but the above code returns the following:

```
sad (2)
grumpy (5)
funny (1)  <--- this is the earlier tag NOT the most recent one
angry (3)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea of laravel, but it seems you're grouping by name, but not using an aggregate function on created_at.

In pure SQL it would be

```
SELECT name, MAX(created_at) FROM yourTable GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/849e3/1/0)

Comment: Even though this isn't in Laravel-specific syntax, it does work flawlessly. I have simply executed it using Laravel's `DB::query()` method. Thank you for the effort and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('tags')->group_by('name')->order_by(DB::raw('MAX(created_at)'))->get(array('name', DB::raw(MAX('created_at'))))
```

Comment: Almost but two issues. One, this is returning them in the reverse order (i.e. the oldest tag first, I'd like the newest first). Swapping MIN() for MAX() doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Second is a typo - I think raw(MAX('created_at')) should be raw('MAX(created_at)')

Comment: Have accepted the answer from tombom but will upvote if you can correct the sql to reverse the order.

Comment: What about order_by(DB::raw('MAX(created_at) DESC')) ?